# Ubuntu 22.04, bash script problem. TAR

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Welcome friends. I wrote a bash script, I'm a novice programmer. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
TIME=`date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M.%S"`
FILE1="my_folder"
FILE2="file_name.sql"
FILE3="script1.sh script2.sh"
cd $HOME
mysqldump -h name_host -u user_mysql -p'password' database_name > file_name.sql
cd $HOME/my_folder/
rm -rf awstats
cd $HOME
tar -zcvf backup_$TIME.tar.gz $FILE1 $FILE2 $FILE3
rm -rf $FILE2
mv backup_$TIME.tar.gz $HOME/backup/
```

When the script is done, I get this message:

```
tar: my_folder: the file has changed while reading it
```

How to fix?

Comment: It's a warning but, the archive should be created fine ... Something in `my_folder` changed during the process ... any services writing to `my_folder`?

Comment: I mean wordpress backup.

Comment: wordpress in `my_folder`? .... Is wordpress being actively used during the backup process?

Comment: It is not used. Could this be the fault of wordpress being hosted a not on the machine?

Comment: This is just a normal warning(not an error) and it is exactly what it says no more ... maybe a file in that directory changed/updated by wordpress or by the webserver or even the system ... If the  backup is created successfully, then I would ignore that message.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to fix the script so that tar won't show me this error?

Comment: Not related to your error, but as a general rule, you want to avoid using CAPS for variables in shell scripts. By convention, global environment variables are capitalized so if you use caps for your own variables that can lead to naming collisions and hard to debug issues. You should also [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222), and there is no need to `cd` somewhere just to delete, you can simply `rm "$HOME"/my_folder/awstats`. You can use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to identify issues in your scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a normal warning(not an error) and it is exactly what it says:

> the file has changed while reading it

no more ... maybe a file in that directory was changed/updated by WordPress or by the web server or even the system ... If the backup is created successfully, then I would ignore that message.

You can, however, suppress that warning by using `--warning=no-file-changed` like so:

```
tar --warning=no-file-changed -zcvf backup ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, you are a good person! :) Now the message is no longer displayed :)